# SP 2016: how to set up the summary view in listviewweb part using powershell?

Tags: powershell, list-view-web-part

I am trying to set the summary view in a list view web part inside a `**Wiki page**`, but it is driving me nuts. I have not been able to solve it. I have spent two day looking around and trying every possible way mentioned in blogs, posts, comments, etc.

Perhaps I am missing something, but I can't seem to find it.

Any help?

```
$spsite = get-spsite "http://site1"
$web = $spsite.RootWeb
$wpPage = $web.GetFile("SitePages/home.aspx")
$WpManager = $wpPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared);
$marketinglist = $web.Lists["Marketing"]
$view = $marketinglist.Views[""]
$newGuid = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
$storageKey = "g_" + $newGuid.Replace("-","_")
$newmarketing = New-Object "Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart"
$newmarketing.ID = $storageKey
#$newmarketing.ViewType = "None"
$newmarketing.ListId = $marketinglist.ID
$newmarketing.ViewGuid = $view.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper()
#$newmarketing.ViewGuid = ""
$newmarketing.Title = "Marketing"
$wpManager.AddWebPart($newmarketing,"wpz",0)
```

Edit:
This blog did not help me either: http://sadomovalex.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/set-summary-view-for-listviewwebpart.html

Comment: why are you doing this in powershell? why not do it in the web part itself?

Comment: do you know a solution for what I am asking?

Comment: No one has a solution for this?

Comment: They might, but when they saw how you responded to me, they opted out. Nobody wants to help a contemptuous user.

Comment: Why do you speak on other people's behalf? Look at your question. How can you ask that when I clearly want to achieve it using PowerShell. If I had to do that manually, I would have explicitly asked for that. Isn't my question obvious?

Comment: BTW, you don't have to answer it, or perhaps you don't know the answer at all. You just beat it around the bush. There are plenty of good knowledgeable people out there who would like to share or help. If not life will go on.